# Cargo fails to select a version for rustc_version

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustup

My project compiles fine on other machines, but on a new one with fresh rustup I get the error

```
$ cargo build
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `rustc_version = "^0.1"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.3.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.1, ...
location searched: crates.io index
```

which doesn't make sense to me. Why does 0.3 not match ^0.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All versions of the `rustc_version` crate before 0.2 have been [yanked](https://crates.io/crates/rustc_version/versions). That and [cargo considers changes to the minor before 1.0 to be incompatible](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#caret-requirements).

It may work on other machines if a pre-0.2 version of `rustc_version` is in their `Cargo.lock` file or if it had already been downloaded and cached.

Comment: Yanked versions can still be downloaded _if they are required by a `Cargo.lock` file,_ but not from `Cargo.toml`. So it should work if you copy the `Cargo.lock` from a working machine to the new one.

Comment: @Jmb oh right, thanks for pointing that out.